# Building lttng-modules using buildroot for a custom kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, buildroot, lttng

I pulled out vanilla 6.5.0 from kernel.org and able to successfully built it for aarch64 using defconfig. For rootfs, I used buildroot and the combo boots fine for me on qemu.

Now I wanted lttng-tools and lttng-modules for this custom built kernel (outside buildroot). Since buildroot provides lttng tools and modules, I want buildroot to build them for me. But the problem is that buildroot does not allow me to select `lttng-modules` unless I have "Kernel" option selected, and selecting that makes buildroot to pull kernel code itself and do a build. What can I do here to achieve my goals (use my custom non-buildroot kernel, but use other lttng and rootfs files from buildroot)?

Comment: What do you think you gain by having a separate kernel build? In the time spent to figure out a working solution, you probably could have simply used Buildroot to build a fresh kernel and rootfs. Then you would be *assured* of a *compatible* kernel and rootfs (containing loadable kernel modules?) all built with a common toolchain.

Comment: I had actually thought of it earlier. But there are two problems with using buildroot for my kernel building. First, is build time, buildroot still goes through entire checks and kernel is just a part of it. Second, I don't want to keep a list of patches for buildroot when I can simply use a separate linux repo and maintain local git history of changes. Please correct me if second one can be overcome. I couldn't find a way to point to local folder.

Comment: "*maintain local git*" - Are you using an obsolete version of Buildroot? Buildroot supports obtaining the kernel from `A set of custom repository locations`, e.g. using a "Custom Git repository", IOW "This option allows Buildroot to get the Linux kernel source
   code from a Git repository".  Hint: "When pointing to a local [] using file://, you may want
   to use a make variable like $(TOPDIR) to reference the root of
   the Buildroot tree."

Comment: But wouldn't it still be making a secondary copy of the source, in its build directories ? So far I always had a separate kernel repo (synced to kernel.org) which I used to prepare my kernel image and modules. I had separate buildroot repo which I used to prepare rootfs tar. Never needed to bring them together. Now I need lttng-modules badly and I just need a way to build them, it would have been lot better if it could use just the kernel headers and give me .ko. This is more ideal and flexible.

Comment: We are using Buildroot with a kernel built elsewhere (https://github.com/andy-shev/buildroot/tree/intel/board/intel/common). What you probably would need is to patch the respective package to get necessary pointers to your external kernel.

Comment: @0andriy This is the exact use case of mine. Thanks. Let me go through it.

Answer (score 1):

You can only build `lttng-modules` when you also build a kernel with Buildroot because building modules requires access to the kernel sources.

The best solution is to build the kernel with Buildroot. You can specify where the kernel is to be downloaded from ("Kernel version" option in the menu). It doesn't have to come from kernel.org.

Alternatively, if you're adamant about building the kernel outside of Buildroot, you have to build any kernel modules outside of Buildroot as well. You're pretty much on your own in that case. The only thing that you can maybe do is to call into Buildroot with `make lttng-modules-source` to download the source tarball. You don't need to have the package configured to call `-source` on it.

Comment: The OP is complicating the alternate "*building the kernel outside of Buildroot*" scenario by wanting to do this *retroactively*. The kernel has been already built, and ideally he seems to want a method that does not require building it again. Buildroot performs well when used in a conventional, straightforward manner. But Buildroot might not perform correctly if you try to force it into an odd situation. Makefiles may not handle every possible contingency.